# UITableViewCell Background Color?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have done a fair bit of googling on this and I can't find the right solution. I have a UITableView of which I want to change the colour of the background of the cells. I have found solutions to doing this but it only deals with cells which have content or data as it were.

I need to colour the background of those unused cells as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting the background colour of the tableView itself. Those "empty cells" at the bottom aren't really cells at all - they're just separator lines drawn over the background.

Comment: Ahh, that would make sense as to why they are unaffected then. `cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];` works, but does't do those blanks and `cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];` doesn't work. Any more ideas?

Comment: Thank you. That makes a lot of sense, and is a really easy fix. I was really struggling with that issue for a while.

Comment: Setting the tableview background colour works, but only on tables with contents. Empty tables are unaffected which I can't have.

Comment: @Josh, you need to use tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; It sounds like you are still trying to set the cell background, not the background of the whole table.

Comment: Yup, sleepy self missed that, but I commented above about tableview colour, see what you think.

Comment: I don't know why empty tables wouldn't be affected by the background colour as well. Do they still have lines drawn across them? Another option is to set the background of your tableview to transparent/clear and then set the background of the view behind the table to blue instead.

Comment: Turns out, I made my code a bit squiffy and I was setting the tableview background colour at the wrong place, but it works now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Even though UITableViewCell inherits from UIView, changing the backgroundColor property of the cell itself won't do anything. You need to change the background color of the cell's contentView, such as

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

This is because the subviews of a UITableViewCell are actually subviews of the cell's contentView, because the contentView knows how to resize its subviews if a cell is put into editing mode; the cell itself doesn't know how to do that.

I'm not sure what you mean by unused cells. If you tell your tableView there are 10 cells and you only provide content for 8 of them, you'll still have 10 green cells, if that's what you mean by "unused".